# Full height in React using flex

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-in-js

I can't find an answer for this, even though there are many `flex` themed questions.

I created a simple React app (`npx create-react-app`).

I then deleted `App.css` and set the contents of `index.css` to:

```css
html, body, #root {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Next, in `App.js` I'm trying to have a full screen element using flex:

```
import React from 'react';


function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', display: "flex", flex: 1 }}>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", flex: 1 }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But it just won't work. Why is the flex element not stretching?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the height of the window you need to mention `height: 100vh` for the parent html tag like:

**Class**-> `.parent{ height: 100vh }`

**Inline style** -> `style={{ height: '100vh' }}`

```
import React from 'react'
 function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', display: "flex", height:'100vh' }}>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", flex: 1 }} >Hello world</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The flex-grow works when there are other elements in the flex. It makes the element to grow x times in comparison to others.

wrt the solution you have implemented: inner `div` doesn't require `display: flex` and direction too. It will be inherited from the parent `div`.

To make the div take the full height. add `height: 100vh` to the parent div.

Let me know if this will solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way of doing this **without** mentioning `height`? I wanted to achieve this using `flex` box.

Comment: I don't think so without height we can do this.